# How to post JSON POST API in PHP file

Tags: php, json, api, post

```
{
"id": "4a59a50e-904a-674d-2553-8954ec4a841d",
"name": "JSON API",
"description": "",
"order": [
    "155ae062-f839-ef5a-6c40-61e821202984"
],
"folders": [],
"folders_order": [],
"timestamp": 1522932542555,
"owner": 0,
"public": false,
"requests": [
    {
        "id": "155ae062-f839-ef5a-6c40-61e821202984",
        "headers": "Authorization: Basic OTE5MTAwMTkxY2OjEyMzQ1Ng==\n",
        "headerData": [
            {
                "key": "Authorization",
                "value": "Basic OTE5MTAwMTkxNjY2OyMzQ1Ng==",
                "description": "",
                "enabled": true
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://apiurl.in/bez/api/v1/documents/upload?disableSms=false",
        "queryParams": [
            {
                "key": "disableSms",
                "value": "false",
                "equals": true,
                "description": "",
                "enabled": true
            }
        ],
        "preRequestScript": null,
        "pathVariables": {},
        "pathVariableData": [],
        "method": "POST",
        "data": [
            {
                "key": "jsonData",
                "value": "{\"phoneNumber\":\"9999999999\",\"merchantId\":\"1122112211\",\"amount\":100,\"billDate\":1514891788753,\"gender\":\"male\",\"ageGroup\":\"21-30\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"12-dec-1989\",\"email\":\"dfgd@gfdgfdg.in\",\"address\":\"dfg\"}",
                "description": "Required fileds\n\"phoneNumber\",\"merchantId\",\"amount\",\"billDate\"\noptional fileds\n\"gender\",\"ageGroup\",\"dateOfBirth\",\"email\",\"address\"",
                "type": "text",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "file",
                "value": "",
                "description": "",
                "type": "file",
                "enabled": true
            }
        ],
        "dataMode": "params",
        "tests": null,
        "currentHelper": "basicAuth",
        "helperAttributes": {
            "id": "basic",
            "username": "0101010101",
            "password": "30303030",
            "saveToRequest": true
        },
        "time": 1514892082233,
        "name": "Bill Uploading",
        "description": "",
        "collectionId": "4a59a50e-904a-674d-2553-8954ec4a841d",
        "responses": [],
        "collection_id": "4a59a50e-904a-674d-2553-8954ec4a841d"
    }
]
  }
```

Above code is in JSON file. I need to use the code in PHP file.

Below code is in PHP. I don't know how to make a POST request through PHP.

```
public function sendSmsApi($array)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['apikey'] = Configuration::get('Sendin_Api_Key');
    $data['to'] = $array['to'];
    $data['sender'] = Configuration::get('sender_id');
    $data['message'] = $array['text'];
    $data['type'] = 'xml';

    return Tools::jsonDecode($this->curlRequest($data));
}
```

How to include JSON Data in PHP and make a POST request to the API URL.
PHP code actually sends the message to customers. I want to include JSON code in PHP file to send A POST Request to API URL.

Comment: You can send a post with `CURL` it's to involved for me to type it all out for you, i suggest googling some tutorials on it.

Comment: Guzzle is a popular HTTP client: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: I think its `Tools::jsonEncode`

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned into above question as a solution please try executing following php code snippet to send json data contained into a json file as a request body of HTTP POST Request.

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://example.com/get-post.php';
$request_params=file_get_contents('test.json');//test.json contains json data
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch) or exit(curl_error($ch));
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: But, I get parameters such as mobile number , amount through PHP. So, How can i pass those values to JSON file.

Comment: You can encode parameters into a json string using json_encode() function and then pass that json string as a request body of POST request

Answer (score 0):

You can read the JSON-file with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) and then parse the string to an PHP-array with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json_string = file_get_contents ('data.json');
$json_array = json_decode ($json_string, true);
```